# Alternative to C++11's std::nextafter and std::nexttoward for C++03?

Tags: c++, floating-point, floating-accuracy, c++03

As the title says, the functionality I'm after is provided by C++11's math libraries to find the next floating point value towards a particular value.

Aside from pulling the code out of the std library (which I may have to resort to), any alternatives to do this with C++03 (using GCC 4.4.6)?

Answer (score 3):

Platform dependently, assuming IEEE754, and modulo endianness, you can store the data of the floating point number in an integer, increment by one, and retrieve the result:

```
float input = 3.15;

uint32_t tmp;

unsigned char * p = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(&tmp);
unsigned char * q = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(&input);

p[0] = q[0]; p[1] = q[1]; p[2] = q[2]; p[3] = q[3];  // endianness?!

++tmp;

q[0] = p[0]; q[1] = p[1]; q[2] = p[2]; q[3] = p[3];

return input;
```

Beware of zeros, NaNs and infinities, of course.

Comment: Note that to decrement a negative float, one must increment its unsigned integer representation.

Comment: [Here is a blog post discussing this approach.](http://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/01/23/stupid-float-tricks-2/)

Comment: What's wrong with a plain `std::copy(p, p+4, q)` ? Or, assuming that the alignment is equal, just `reinterpret_cast<uint32_t&>(input)++;`

Comment: You're being a bit too complicated.  `memcpy` does what you want.  And on most machines, `reinterpret_cast<unsigned const*>( &input )`, or putting them into a `union`.  (And endianness will only be an issue if floats and ints have different endianness---something I've never heard of.)

Comment: @MSalters: `std::copy` is fine. I didn't feel like using the library today. Your direct cast is UB.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Perhaps, but it was platform-dependent anyway and I've seen better code being generated that way (compiler keeping the variable in the same register).

Comment: @MSalters: Hmm... typical processors have a separate set of registers for floating point numbers...

Comment: @KerrekSB: In hindsight, that is the smarter CPU design. It allows you to have more registers for the same instruction length, since the opcode helps disambiguate between int register 0 and FP register 0. But as x86 shows, ISA design is more art then science.

Comment: @MSalters: Well, once you take the address of something, I suppose the thing has to be written to memory anyway...

Comment: @KerrekSB: That's the nice thing of `reinterpret_cast<uint32_t&>`, no address is involved. And on my target, which doesn't have distinct FP registers, it didn't even involve a register-to-register copy.

Comment: [using `reinterpret_cast` for type punning still invokes undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53995657/995714)

Answer (score 0):

I realize this answer is quite late, but I stumbled upon the solution when I needed something very similar, so figured this should be included here for completeness. In C++11, the mentioned APIs are in the 'std' namespace. Prior to that, just remove the 'std' namespace qualifier, from math.h:

```
     double nextafter  (double x     , double y);
      float nextafterf (float x      , float y);
long double nextafterl (long double x, long double y);
```

Although I don't have GCC4.4.6 to validate, this did work for me on an old compiler that does not support C++11.